# Angular 2: Two different types with this name exist

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 app, I have following code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscription } from '@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/rxjs/Rx';
...
private broadcastDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<Event>;
...
let sub: Subscription = this.broadcastDataSubject.asObservable().subject(event).subscribe(() => this.bla());
```

Problem is in the last row, code will not complile because of:

**"Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated."**

I have same code in my second project and it runs without problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that I had **2 same imports**:

```
import { Subscription } from '@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/rxjs/Rx';
```

One in the **component** and one in **service**.

Comment: I was in the process of answering this question-- it also seems strange that you're importing RxJs from two different locations

Comment: Could you clarify why this is a problem? Was this really what was the matter? I have identical import statements all over the place wherever the same thing is needed in multiple places. I can see how importing from two different installations of Rx would be a problem though.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue until I saw that I was importing my Observable from:

```
import { Observable } from '@firebase/util';
```

I changed it to:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and it was working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error when I misspelt *Observable*. In the import
I wrote:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
```

where as it should be

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

P.S. this was for the version 5.2.11