# Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, yarnpkg

I get this error when building my JHipster Angular project. It happens after command `yarn start`

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { JhiEventManager, JhiParseLinks, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { ITEMS_PER_PAGE, Principal } from '../../shared';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
....
private subscription: Subscription;
    private eventSubscriber: Subscription;
...
 ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            this.load(params['id']);
        });
}


> TS90010: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.
> Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
```

But it worked previously without problem. I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: Could you please provide code where the error appeared? It is hard to say from two error lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331230/angular-2-two-different-types-with-this-name-exist]

Comment: @JosefKatič i provided a code from one of many component where the error appeared.

Comment: My intuition tells me you save the subscription to unsubscribe from it in ngOnDestroy. Since it's native from Angular, you do not need to do this, so you could probably skip that piece of code unless you have other use for it. Also, you can import Observable and Subscription from 'rxjs'

Comment: @YuriiBidiuk Are you sure that you import `Subscription` everywhere from the same source?

Comment: @JosefKatič yes.  Everywhere it imported from rxjs. But as i mentioned, it worked perfectly before.

Comment: Try to re-run `ng serve`. Sometimes it solves some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

to this

`import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer your question directly but instead of keeping track of all your subscriptions with subscription objects just use one Subject and do take until. That is the recommended way of managing rxjs subscriptions in Angular.

```
finalise = new Subject<void>();

this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.load(params['id']);
}).pipe(takeUntil(this.finalise)); // No need to unsubscribe if finalise emits.

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.finalise.next();
  this.finalise.complete();
}
```

Now you only need one object to manage all the subscription in the component.